# How do I log onto my windows 10 pc without the use of a keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I recently got the k70 rgb corsair keyboard, and I was looking at some tutorial and during the tutorial it told me to go to my keyboard settings and disable all my keyboards within the computer. Stupidly, it told my to restart my computer, which I did. However, when I did I still have to log in to the computer using a worded password.. what do I do?

Comment: Try the on-screen keyboard from the accessibility tools button on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

As [Bob](https://superuser.com/questions/1187942/how-do-i-log-onto-my-windows-10-pc-without-the-use-of-a-keyboard#comment1722484_1187942) said, there should be the "accessibility" menu button on your login screen.

Someone else asked the same question on [Microsoft community's forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-login-prompt-on-screen-keyboard-or/f257096f-b9c1-46f9-ac10-074d17cdb0de)